# Seeing debug traces without a debugger?

Tags: .net, trace

How can one look at .NET Debug.WriteLine traces outside the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use **[DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx)** from Sysinternals or add the following to your applications [config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(VS.80).aspx) to trace messages to the console:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="TraceTest" switchName="SourceSwitch" 
        switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="console" />
          <remove name ="Default" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <!-- You can set the level at which tracing is to occur -->
      <add name="SourceSwitch" value="Warning" />
        <!-- You can turn tracing off -->
        <!--add name="SourceSwitch" value="Off" -->
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="console" 
        type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" 
        initializeData="false"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="console" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

You can also change the type of the trace listener in the log file from `System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener` to any other trace listener, e.g. to log to the system's EventLog  or to trace to a custom application.

Comment: I tried adding a <AppName>.exe.config file, with the above contents, in the same folder as my executable, but nothing happened when the program traced stuff. I also tried System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener in the config file as suggested at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener(VS.80).aspx, which worked only if there was lots of trace data -- apparently it doesn't flush the file automatically.

Comment: Follow up: autoflush="false" must be changed to autoflush="true". And it's too bad I can't get the console trace listener working. Worst of all it doesn't work on a Release build, even though I have defined TRACE!

Comment: Oh I see, I have to use Trace.WriteLine instead of Debug.WriteLine for the TRACE constant to work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx). I have not used this with .NET, but I have used it with VC++ apps.

Comment: It captures traces for the whole system. I'd like something I can give to another engineer and say "just use this to see the traces"; unfortunately this tool produces a lot of noise and I don't see an obvious way to filter just my app. Also unfortunate is that my app contains C++ code that also produces irrelevant traces I would like to hide - so a .NET-only trace would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dbgview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx)